# Background for Android Layout

Tags: android, layout, background, overlay

How do I add the basic gray/black holo background to a `TextView` and a `SeekBar`. Both are overlayed over a camera preview contained by the `FrameLayout`. Currently both are barely visibile because of the missing background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/scanner_camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scanner_help_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Den Zoom-Regler benutzen um den Barcode auszuwählen." />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/scanner_camera_seek"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/scanner_help_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your XML Layout to this..I have added purple color for text view and red color for seekbar. Change as per your needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/scanner_camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scanner_help_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:text="Den Zoom-Regler benutzen um den Barcode auszuwählen." />

    <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/scanner_camera_seek"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/scanner_help_text"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How do I choose the background color currently used by my activity?

Comment: @multiholle: Can you explain it briefly? You need background as dynamic ?

Comment: Depending on the theme, the background might be light or dark. How do I get the current used color?

Comment: By default, it will be set as Black. We need to change it as per our needs. Doubts cleared ?

Comment: @multiholle: If you are cleared with the answer, don't forget to select tick mark! so that it will be useful to others to found the solution

Answer (score -1):

```
android:background="@drawable/yourdrawable"
```

Comment: I don't want to add a background image.